# Partitioning to the "left" after deleting a Windows partition?

Tags: partitioning, windows, gparted

I deleted my Windows partition so I can make more space for my Ubuntu partition (making the switch out of Windows.) but I found out that you can't resize to the left, is there any way I can use the unallocated space? (that's why I added the quotes around left in the question)
[If you need an image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjqQW.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can resize to the left or right, it is written as space preceeding and space following.

But
First you will have to boot from a live disk inorder to resize your partitions on your hard disk.

Then you will have to first resize your extended partition.
Then you would be able to resize your ubuntu partition,

BUT it would give a warning that moving root partitons can lead to boot failure.

So best option is to right click on the unallocated space and click on new to create a new partition, choose type as ext4.

This partiton you could use in ubuntu to store your data instead of resizing the ubuntu partition.

Answer (score 1):

`gparted` will let you move and resize partitions.  If you move the start of a partition it will need to do it in two operations, a move and a resize (the order of which depends on which direction you move it).

You will obviously need to do this from a live CD, because you can't move a partition that is currently in use.

Answer (score 1):

Aaditya Bagga and neon_overload are both correct; however, I want to add that *any* partition resizing operation is somewhat risky, and any operation that moves the start point of the partition is *especially* risky. The reason should be clear from the other users' answers: Such operations involve more manipulation of data than a resize from the end of the partition. This increases the time involved (and therefore the risk from a power failure or system crash) and simply gives more opportunities for any of a million other potential problems to crop up. I don't want to overstate this, though; the risk of failure is still fairly small. The trouble is that the consequences of failure can often be dire, particularly if you lack good backups.

Instead of resizing the partition in this way, you might want to consider creating a new partition in the empty space and mounting it somewhere convenient in your directory tree. You can then either populate it with new files or move existing files there. The details of what you might do depend on the sizes of existing partitions and of the space you've freed, how you're using your system, etc. Therefore, I can't be very specific with suggestions.

If you really want or need to resize the partition from the start, I *strongly* recommend doing a backup of that partition to an external medium before you begin.

Comment: I could always just re-install the OS and give a fresh start, but thank you all for the help.